# How to add OR for adding multiple gate permissions at construct method of controller

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-5.8, laravel-gate

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I have created this method in the Controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('can:see-brand-requests')->only(['index']);
    }
```

Now I need to say if user has one of these permissions, the show the `index` method:

```
brand-owner-info,brand-overall-info,brand-employees-info,brand-actions,see-brand-requests
```

So how can I add OR in this case to the Middleware?

Comment: do you use the Spatie permission package ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following.

```
@canany(['show-permissions','show-roles'])

@endcan
```

Find out more information here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization.